# What authentication methods are supported by the Windows 10 WebDav client in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, authentication, webdav

The native WebDav client accessible from Windows Explorer on Windows 10 supports Basic Authentication and client certificate authentication.

Are other authentication methods supported such as Oauth or SAML, and if so, what are they?